# Why won't my jQuery selector work for IDs with colons and periods in them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a script that's supposed to dynamically place divs containing group member names inside one container div. These divs are ID'd by the concatenation of "groupMemberEntryDiv" and the group member's e-mail address (which is unique in my system).

The problem is that using the IDs in jQuery selectors doesn't work. I believe I've covered all the possible hangups that could be causing this problem:

1. The presence of '@' in e-mail addresses (element IDs cannot contain this character). I've fixed this by replacing them with ':', which is allowed character. Also, since ':' does not appear in valid e-mail addresses, I can use indexOf to parse the string and replace it with '@' when I need to use the e-mail address again.
2. The presence of ':' and '.' in (the now modified) e-mail addresses ([jQuery may see them as pseudo-classes and classes respectively](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions)). Following the instructions in that page, I have tried to escape the characters. In fact, I lifted the .replace() function from that very link to do so.

Unfortunately, the selectors still won't work. I've created a simple [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jqut7/3/) to illustrate the problem.

Can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: Doesn't seems to be a good idea to have members emails visible in your markup for everyone. You should use some numeric ID.

Comment: @BoltClock. you certainly can have them in an ID, it just messes up the selectors so you have to escape them

Comment: @morgar: My system is setup so that "adding" someone as a contact requires knowing their e-mail address to send the request.

Comment: @Neal: so what happens if I have `id='blah:hover'`? Is that valid? How will CSS deal with it?

Comment: @BoltClock: *"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."*

Comment: @Kevin Still a bad idea, but, you could use data-* attributes to store the email addresses instead. ie, `<div id="user-323" data-email="will_get_spammed@gmail.com"><div>`, then accessed with `$('#user-323').data('email');`

Comment: @BoltClock: You are incorrect. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: @Spudley it will escape the character as you see in @Chad's answer below

Comment: Oops. I must have mixed it up with some other attribute.

Comment: why not put the email address in a hidden <span as <div id="blahblah><span>[email address]    hopefully that page is only visible to a small group, otherwise spammers gonna harvest them from your site.

Comment: @Dreaded semicolon: I guess I should explain my system more. These groups are categories that a user can place their contacts in. In order for two users to have a contact relationship ("friendship"), one must use the other's e-mail along with a numeric code chosen by the receiving user. If the e-mail is in the system and the code is correct, then the request is sent. Maximum of two attempted requests to the same e-mail address in 24 hours to deter spammers. So, it is a given that any contacts a user can categorize in to groups is a friend of the user whose e-mail address the user already knows

Comment: ...continued @Dreaded semicolon: Knowing this, how can this be used by spammers? I want to make this as secure as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are escaping the special characters (which is correct for the selector) but the ID doesn't need to be escaped. Consider:

```
$("#protectedGroupDiv100").append("<div id='groupMemberEntryDiv"  + emailString + "' class='groupMemberEntryDivs'>hey</div>");
```

Generates:

```
<div id="groupMemberEntryDivblahblah\:gmail\.com" class="groupMemberEntryDivs"></div>
```

See how this creates an element with id of: `#groupMemberEntryDivblahblah\:gmail\.com`
but later you use the selector of `#groupMemberEntryDivblahblah\:gmail\.com` which seems the same but what jQuery looks for is actually `#groupMemberEntryDivblahblah:gmail.com`. Since the ID of your element has backslashes in it, jQuery finds no match for the selector.

To fix this set the ID before you escape it:

```
$.each(emailArray, function(index, emailString){
    emailString = emailString.replace("@", ":");            //Element attributes cannot contain "@"

    $("#protectedGroupDiv100").append("<div id='groupMemberEntryDiv"  + emailString + "' class='groupMemberEntryDivs'>hey</div>");

    emailString = emailString.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\$1');    //Escape ':' and '.'

   alert($("#groupMemberEntryDiv"  + emailString).length);                  
});
```

Here is a modified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jqut7/8/).

Though this works, I do not recomend having user emails in the markup. As others have hinted to it can lead to security issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what security issues can it lead to if users are required to know the e-mails of their contacts in order to send them a "friend request" in the first place?

Comment: Spam bots can crawl the page and gather emails, I can see peoples emails that I don't even know and use that to gain access to their account, etc, etc...

Comment: @Chad: I guess I should explain my system more. These groups are categories that a user can place their contacts in. In order for two users to have a contact relationship ("friendship"), one must use the other's e-mail along with a numeric code chosen by the receiving user. If the e-mail is in the system and the code is correct, then the request is sent. Maximum of two attempted requests to the same e-mail address in 24 hours to deter spammers. So, it is a given that any contacts a user can categorize in to groups is a friend of the user whose e-mail address the user already knows

Comment: ...continued @Chad: Knowing this, how can this be used by spammers? I want to make this as secure as possible.

Comment: If getting to the page this content is on requires login, and once there you can only view emails that were already associated to your account (friends) then you should be fine.

Comment: Just a heads up. If you're using jsps you're going to have to include an extra set of backslaches (.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\\\$1')). The first set of backslashes results in one backslash that is eaten by Java unless you escape it with another backslash.